# Setting GitHub Actions Secrets on Docker container build/run command, but encountering a parsing issue

Tags: bash, shell, docker, github

I'm in the early stages of building an automated pipeline. Still in the exploring phase. Right now, I'm struggling with setting the environment variables for the container I'm going to run my app.

The idea is to have my environment variables set as GitHub Actions Secrets and configure them in the container when I run the docker container command. The container was built out of a Docker Composer file.

Right now, I have this test script (A) working perfectly:

```yaml
- name: Backend - Build Container (proof of concept)
  run: |
    BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT="TEST_1='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' TEST_2='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' GITHUB_USER='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' GITHUB_REPO_NAME='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml up -d && docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml logs; exit;";    
    ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_ssh_key_server_temp.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_IP }} "$BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT"
```

However, my idea it to build a temporary file (ss-build-files/output-docker-compose-github-secrets.txt), that looks literally like this:

```sh
TEST_1='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' TEST_2='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' GITHUB_USER='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' GITHUB_REPO_NAME='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}'
```

(It will be built dynamically by a node file, based on the secret keys in the repo)

Problem is when I try to merge the two together:

```yaml
- name: Backend - Build Container (proof of concept)
  run: |
    BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT="$(cat ss-build-files/output-docker-compose-github-secrets.txt) docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml up -d && docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml logs; exit;";
    ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_ssh_key_server_temp.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_IP }} "$BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT"
```

So, in my mind, this would 'translate' into:

```sh
BACKEND_CONTAINER_SH_SCRIPT="TEST_1='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' TEST_2='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' GITHUB_USER='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' GITHUB_REPO_NAME='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml up -d && docker-compose -f ss-build-files/ubuntu-container-build.yml logs; exit;";
```

The container gets built without any error. What happens is, that when I get into the container to debug the environment values, I get something this:

```sh
GITHUB_USER=${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}
GITHUB_REPO_NAME=${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}
```

(literal values)
Note: The test script (A) that worked perfectly prints out the correct secret values.

Is there a parsing details I'm missing in this constructed command? I'm not so advanced in shell script. Preferably grabbing the output string from this file `ss-build-files/output-docker-compose-github-secrets.txt`. I have flexibility on changing details in the output (single quotes, double, no quotes).

Any other suggestion? Even it it meant looping through an array of secret keys to build this command `TEST_1='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' TEST_2='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}' GITHUB_USER='${{ secrets.TEST_1 }}' GITHUB_REPO_NAME='${{ secrets.TEST_2 }}'` so they could reflect the correct values.